# Trying to implement audit in my Play framework application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I've done a fair amount of research to find audit library which integrated well with JPA and Java/Play.

I found nothing simple and ready to use (I'm maybe wrong about this). However I found this :

http://code.google.com/p/simplejpa/wiki/EntityListeners

And I have implemented simple AuditListener class that has two simple methods :

```
@PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof MyObj){
            MyObj brand = (MyObj) object;
            Logger.info("waaaa " + br.toString());
        }
    }

@PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof Brand){
            MyObj br = (MyObj) object;
            Logger.info("waaaazaa update" + br.toString());
        }
    }
```

And I'm able to debug the code and I can see that this is working. However I'm supposed to develop some auditing mechanism that later on is going to know what has changed on the certain object.

Ex :

```
Obj a = new Obj();
a.name = "My name is T";
a.save();
```

And this would trigger prepresist, and nothing has changed in this case I can just simply write to my audit table, new object created. However if the update happens :

```
Obj a = getItFromMyDB;
a.name "My name has changed";
a.update();
```

The PreUpdate is triggered. How would I know what the value of this object was before it was updated?

In this preupdate method I get only the new updated object. If I knew how to get the "old" object I could then compare them and save the change in my audit db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers)? You annotate your persistent class, or some of its properties that you want to audit, with @Audited. For each audited entity a table will be created that will hold the history of changes made to the entity. You can then retrieve and query historical data.

Phil Wilson has written a good article on using Envers from Play!

http://philwilson.org/blog/2012/06/logging-database-content-changes-in-a-play-framework-app